Which macOS Terminal settings impact whether program output freezes terminal *input*?
Both myself and my colleague are running the following OSX version:
sw_vers
ProductName:            macOS
ProductVersion:         14.6.1
BuildVersion:           23G93

When we both run RpcExplorer against an internal endpoint, it prints some output and then our terminal behavior diverges.

On my terminal, RpcExplorer continues to accept input and function normally.
On his terminal, it appears that RpcExplorer is no longer receiving any input. Even Control+C is not passed to the process.

My suspicion is that certain output rendered by curses is causing the terminal to start capturing input and cease forwarding it to the process, but I am confused about why it only impacts his terminal and not mine.
Are there any terminal settings that might cause input suspension on certain program outputs?
Note that I am relatively certain that there is an input issue rather than an output issue, because I recompiled RpcExplorer with debugging statements to detect when input is read, and there is no input read after his terminal freezes.

ControlS will do that.

@ThomasDickey It prevents the user's input from reaching the process?

As far as I can tell empirically, Control-S prevents output, but it does not prevent Control-C from killing the process.
